# How to install libraries like cairomm-devel, pandomm-devel on Aws Linux AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

How to install libraries like cairomm-devel,pangomm-devel those packages are not in Amazon Linux AMI.
But i need those libraries.
How do i install those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution Amazon Linux does not have those libraries required.
I fixed by migrating my server to Docker Instance using AWS Fargate (Serverless Approach).